# How best can I refine this irregular table and its ungainly code?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to create an HTML design board inspired by this [basic board.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QioQg.png)

This is my result after a bit of mucking about:

```html
<table width="500px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="100px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="border: 2px solid white;" width="100px" height="100px">
        <div style="background-color:tomato; height:100%; width: 100%;">A</div>
      </td>
      <td style="border: 2px solid white;" width="100px" height="100px">
        <div style="background-color:tomato; height:100%; width: 100%;"></div>
      </td>
      <td style="border: 2px solid white;" width="100px" height="100px">
        <div style="background-color:tomato; height:100%; width: 100%;"></div>
      </td>
      <td style="border: 2px solid white;" width="100px" height="100px">
        <div style="background-color:tomato; height:100%; width: 100%;"></div>
      </td>
      <td style=" border: 1px solid white;" width="100px" height="100px">
        <div style="background-color:tomato; height:100%; width: 100%;"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table width="498px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="200px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div style="background-color:white; border: 1px solid white; height:100%; width: 100%; background-color: tomato;"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table width="502px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="1" style="width: 400px; height:180px; background-color:tomato;border: 2px solid white;border-top: 4px solid white;">H</td>
      <td colspan="1" style="width: 168px;background-color:tomato;border: 1px solid white;border-top: 4px solid white;">I</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="501px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="border: 2px solid white; background-color:tomato;" width="132px">A</td>
      <td style=" border: 2px solid white;" width="217px" height="238px">
        <div style="background-color:skyblue; height: 100%; width: 100%;">s</div>
      </td>
      <td style=" border: 1px solid white;" width="147px">
        <div style="background-color:tomato; height:285px; width: 100%; margin-top:-50px; border: 1px solid white;border-top: 4px solid white;"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 282px; top:367px;">
  <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; margin: 25px; -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); transform: rotate(-45deg); overflow: hidden; border: 4px solid white;">
    <div style="background: tomato; width: 150px; height: 150px; margin: -25px; -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); transform: rotate(45deg);"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, it's hideous and clumsy and comprised of an awkward mix of HTML and divs, but (basically... kind of...) gets the job done.  (I know there are loads of mistakes in it, but I've not even tried cleaning it up yet.  If there's a preferred method, I would rather not pour any more time into this beast.)

The sheer convoluted-ness of the code suggests there's likely an easier way accomplish this.  But, there are fundamental issues hemming, in which methods are available for design purposes.  The place where this code will eventually be used does not allow CSS outside of inline, and it cannot use JavaScript.

As is probably obvious by this point, I'm not really experienced in this sort of thing at all, so I apologize in advance if this is a staggeringly stupid question.

But, given the restrictions, is this kind of HTML/CSS amalgam the best way to handle designing something of this nature?  Or can someone recommend a cleaner means of getting it done?

Comment: Why are you going for table as div takes much less code?

Comment: Tables are not the right approach for layout .Use flexbox approach for this layout

Answer (score 0):

As to the goal of "cleaning it up", I suggest using an external CSS style sheet instead of the inline style definitions that your HTML elements are using. This should enable you to encapsulate the CSS style definitions apart from the basic HTML layout. The end result should require much less text in your HTML file.

This [w3schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) covers this and their example of an inline CSS file reference is shown in the following image.

[image]